# What features will I miss if I move apps to SD card?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, apps, storage

I want know to what features -in general- will I lose after moving apps from internal to external storage. I'm using SD card class 10. I'm thinking about moving some apps like Facebook, Viber, WhatsApp, Microsoft Translator, Word, Excel, PowerPoint.

I have tried moving Xodo to SD card. Since then the app crashes multiple times and lags a lot and sometimes won't start unless I restart the device.

I am not willing to suffer the same horrible scenario with the above  mentioned apps.

Comment: Note that SD card "classes" are based on *bulk* I/O speed, not on random access speed. Bulk speed is usually pretty irrelevant for phone apps - any individual file in an app bundle is going to be pretty small - but random-access speed can be a big deal. Sometimes "slower" cards are actually faster when you're running software from them (though they will still be slower when doing things like saving/copying a video to them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App crashes which is in SD card mostly happens when the app hasn't move successfully to SD card. In that case what I do is i move those apps to phone memory again and after that again I move them to SD card. And that's works for me. 
I will suggest you to move apps one by one and checking them that they are working or not? And also while moving apps in that process don't go forward or backward. In short, don't give any interrupt otherwise process may endup with app crash.

**Note - Some app developer won't give permission to move their apps to SD card memory.**